# How To Auto `command -p` In All My Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell-builtin

I want to execute all commands within my script with `command -p` e.g.:

```bash
command -p pwd
```

Because there may be some command that I will execute within the script whose name is being used by some other custom user script and in this case the `command` command causes the system command to be executed and not the user's (this is a friendly explanation, if you want a technical understanding of what really happens behind the scenes, consult the man page) which is what I want.

Well, so that I don't always have to literally type "`command -p`" at the beginning of the line every time I invoke any command within the script, is there any way to define the behavior of `command -p` globally in the script?

Comment: ??  If you want to execute all the commands in your script, why can't you do that by just ***executing the script***?; i.e. `./<scriptname>`

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: I certainly didn't know how to be clear with my words, I edited the question. Can you read it again?

Comment: @Seamus They *are* executing the script. The question is about how the script finds command that it executes. They don't want the user's `$PATH` to cause it to use the incorrect version of tools.

Comment: @Barmar: Oh - my mistake... `command` is actually a command. :)

Comment: @Seamus yes, it can be confusing when a common meta-variable becomes an actual variable/command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell looks for executable files in its `PATH` to execute. You can exclude user writable directories from the `PATH` variable for a much more elegant solution. So at the start of the script add:

```
PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/:/sbin/:/usr/local/games:/usr/games'
```

Comment: This may be even better than `command -p` for what the OP wants to do. E.g. `command -p sh -c 'shell code'` makes Bash use the default `PATH` while searching for `sh`, but the environment of `sh` will be unaffected, so `shell code` will be interpreted according to the actual `PATH` variable anyway.

Comment: And anyways I'm not aware of any method to add `command -p` before every single command. It is possible for limited commands using aliases, but it is a janky, fragile solution.

Wouldn't also adding `command` before any command introduce additional overhead?

Comment: @td211 It definitely seems like the best option. Is there a way to instead define the PATH manually and get the default value from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I didn't exactly understand what you meant @rhuanpk

Comment: @td211 The way you presented the solution, you defined the PATH variable manually, right? You yourself put the "default" folders in the PATH variable. My question is if there is somewhere that stores the default folders in the PATH variable so that I can make this automatic and not manual.

Comment: It depends on the distribution you are using. You can put this in `~/.bashrc` however I prefer that you perform this manual override per script.

Comment: @td211 Actually, that's not what I wanted to ask. I will try to simplify and make the question more direct. When the command `command -p` looks for the command it will execute in the default `PATH`, where is this `PATH`? Where does he get this information from? Where is the default `PATH` information stored?

Comment: `PATH` is an environment variable. `command -p` will look for binaries in a bunch of default directories not in you current `PATH` variable. @rhuanpk

Comment: Okay, I understand that. And where is this `PATH` environment variable that the `command -p` look at (which is not my current `PATH` variable) set? What static file or script does the system read from? @td211

Comment: I don't know honestly, it is probably a `POSIX` thing compiled directly into `bash`. Just override `PATH` manually, I don't see why you want to hack the `command -p`. @rhuanpk

Answer (score 5):

```
PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH)${PATH+:$PATH}
```

Would put *a* POSIX search path ahead of $PATH.

You'll find that command above is given as and example in [the specification of the standard `command` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html).

For that to work, that needs to be run from a POSIX shell already for it to support `command -p`.

On systems that support more than one version of the standard, like on Solaris where there's a /use/xpg6/bin with commands (including `getconf`) whose behaviour is different from those in /use/xpg4/bin, which you'll get may depend on the initial environment.

Whether the value of $PATH will affect the behaviour of shell builtins also depends on the shell.

Comment: You should probably quote this to avoid word splitting (unlikely to have a space in `PATH` but not impossible)

Comment: @td211 there's no split+glob in assignments to scalar variables.

Comment: FWIW, Termux `getconf PATH` reports `getconf: PATH: unknown variable`